# Is it possible to hide both value AND percentage in the label of an Excel chart when the value is 0?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, format, label

We use both the value and percentages in the label of our charts, and I would like to know if there is a way to hide both when the value is 0. I understand how to hide it with the number format code if it's just a value or just a percentage, but I don't know how to hide it if we display both. Is it possible at all? Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these, will help you to get rid from Zero vale.**

- **R**ight click on Label & hit **F**ormat Data Labels.
- Then **N**umber & **C**ustom.
- Now enter the format `#""` as **C**ustom Number Format.
- **R**epeat for others.
- Now **Z**eros will replace with **B**lank.

**N.B.**

- *This works with all versions higher that Excel 2010.*
- *If you want to display Zero then use  this cell format `#,##0;-#,##0`.*

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it would solve the problem if it was just the value. But as I mentioned, its the value and the percentage as well. (So my question is about a number format which can remove zero when both the value and the percentage is shown.) As a workaround I changed the 0 to N/A and now it works as if there were no 0s, so the question is kind of solved.

Comment: @MatthiasS share the screen shot !