# How to Hide Series Name Label, Call Out Box & Zero Value in Chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, label, hide

I've seen a variant of this question asked a number of times, but none seem to deal with my particular problem.  In my stacked bar chart I use a Series Name label.  I'd like it to go away altogether when the value is 0.

Here is how it looks:
[image]

To get rid of the 0 value, I use the trick from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/654279/how-can-i-hide-0-value-data-labels-in-an-excel-chart) (and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1678844/is-it-possible-to-hide-both-value-and-percentage-in-the-label-of-an-excel-chart), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500196/hiding-zero-values-in-excel-chart-or-diagram-legend-and-labeling), and...) and change the number format to: `#""%;;;`

When I do that, the chart looks like this:
[image]

Still not what I want.  I need the series name label to disappear as well as the call out box.  I found two answers that recommended using a NA() to get rid of the label ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34667784/suppressing-data-labels-in-excel-if-n-a-value) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65880979/hide-zero-value-data-labels-for-excel-charts-with-category-name)).  I had to add a second row of labels and set the series label for the blue & orange bars separately, but still it didn't work.  Here is the formula I used: `=IF(D4=0,NA(),"Prefer Not to Answer")`

[image]

So the first problem is why is it still displaying the error?  If that is resolved the second problem will be whether or not the call out box disappears as well.  Help?

Comment: You want `#N/A` to be instead of the value (the 0% in this case), not the header

Comment: Oh.

Haha, well, that's easy then.  Fixed!  Thanks!!